# NameError: name 'request' is not defined in python

Tags: python, flask

I run the following code on python:

```
from flask import Flask

 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])

 def verify():
    if request.args.get("hub.mode") == "subscribe" and request.args.get("hub.challenge"):
        if not request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == 
 os.environ ["VERIFY_TOKEN"]:
            return "Verification token mismatch", 403
        return request.args["hub.challenge"], 200
return "Hello world", 200
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And got this error:

> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Answer (score 7):

You need to import the `flask.request`:

```
from flask import request
```